# Polynomial $f(X) g(Y)- g(X) f(Y)$ irreducible in $F[X,Y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field and $f(X), g(X) \in F[X]$ two *coprime*
non constant polynomials.

Question: Is the polynomial $P(X,Y):= f(X)  g(Y)- g(X)  f(Y)$
irreducible in the ring $F[X,Y]$ of polynomials in two variables?

The claim is clearly wrong if $f$ and $g$ are not coprime, so it's neccessary assumption. A possible approach I used was to divide $P(X,Y)$ by $f(X)$ and think
about the polynomial $g(Y)-S \cdot f(Y) \in F[S][Y]$ where
$S:= g(X)/f(X)$ and because the extension of $F$ by $F(S)$ is
transcendental we can regard $S$ as a variable. I know that
$g(Y)-S \cdot f(Y) $ is irreducible in $F[S][Y]$ but not know
how it helps to answer the question if $P(X,Y)$ is irreducible in $F[X,Y]$.

Comment: I think it is always divisible by $X-Y$. By the degree argument, it is not irreducible, hence not prime in general.

Comment: could you shortly elaborate what you mean by 'degree argument'? wrt $X$ (or by symmetry of $Y$) or the total degree counting maximal exponent in $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: I think Youngsu means that the degree of the polynomial $P(X,Y)$ is at least 2. Hence it cannot be $P(X,Y)=X-Y$. Since $P(X,Y)$ is a multiple of $X-Y$, it is always reducible.

Comment: @Crostul hmm, that's not quite right; if $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=t+1$ then $p(x,y)=x-y$

Comment: (however, if you choose $f$ and $g$ to have constant term $0$, then what you say holds. this condition isn't necessary though; for instance, if $f(t)=t^2$ and $g(t)=t^2+1$, then $p(x,y)=(x-y)(x+y)$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the ring $F(X)[Y]/(X-Y)$, you have
$$P(X,Y)\bmod (X-Y)= f(X)  g(X)- g(X)  f(X)=0,$$
hence $P(X,Y)$ is divisible by $X-Y$.